# Trying to add SMS Participant to twilio Conversation in JS - Error 20403 - 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-conversations

I'm trying to add an SMS Participant to Twilio an existing Twilio conversation using this API fetch.
`snapshot.node_.value_` is the conversation ID `CHXXXXXX...` and both phone numbers are actual values in the real code, not just `+1XXXXX`

```js
fetch(`https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/${snapshot.node_.value_}/Participants/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa(`${twilioAccountSID}:${twilioAuthToken}`)
    }),
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        "MessagingBinding.Address":"+1XXXXXXXXXX",//Personal phone number
        "MessagingBinging.ProxyAddress":"+1XXXXXXXXXX"//Twilio phone number
    }),
    redirect: 'follow'
})
```

Unfortunately when I catch and log an error I get `{"code": 20403, "message": "403 Forbidden", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20403", "status": 403}`

The more info page is pretty unhelpful.
I'm currently on a twilio trial account, but nothing in the trial limitations mentions conversations.
I am able to use a matching API call successfully when I use Postman.

Comment: Are you able to compare the result of `'Basic '+btoa(\`${twilioAccountSID}:${twilioAuthToken}\`)` with the one generated by Postman?

Comment: Where in Postman do I go to see that generated?

Comment: Do you have it under the tab "Headers" > "Temporary Headers" > "Authorization"?

Comment: Are you making this call from the client side of your application?